# Run an external file using sql server

Tags: sql-server, external

I have an excel sheet that import/export data from/to many other sheets. I want SQL server to open it and then close it just to refresh its data every hour for example.
I tried this code:

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(512),
        @status int,
        @Excel int,
        @WorkBook int

IF ((DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) <> 7) and (DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) >=09 and (DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) <=16)) ) 
or ((DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) =7) and (DATEPART(hh,GETDATE()) >=15)) BEGIN


SET @filename = 'd:\xxx.xlsb'        -- excel filename
--SET @filename = 'd:\2020\2020.xlsb'

SET @status = 0
EXEC @status = sp_OACreate 'Excel.Application', @Excel output
--if 1= 1 
begin
IF @status=0 EXEC @status = sp_OAMethod @Excel, 'WorkBooks.Open', @WorkBook output, @FileName

IF @status=0 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Excel, 'Workbooks(1).refreshall'

waitfor delay '00:01'
--ADD code to run macros??(IF @status=0 EXEC sp_OAMethod @Excel, 'Application.Run' ('sheet3change'))??
 
print @Status
 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Excel, 'ActiveWorkbook.Save'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Excel, 'Workbooks.Close'
exec sp_oaMethod @Excel,'Application.Quit'  
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Excel, 'Close'
 
IF @status <> 0
BEGIN
    raiserror ('errors', 15, 1)
END


EXEC sp_OADestroy @WorkBook
end 
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Excel

end 
waitfor delay '00:01'
```

but it gave me this error:
" msg 50000, level 15 , state 1 , line 33
errors ".
I've tested it on another Laptop and it seemed to work fine without any errors.
I'm sure of the paths and I'm sure that I used the same code on both Laps.

could anyone help me out here ?

Comment: Automating Excel is a bad idea in general; automating Excel from SQL Server is a downright terrible idea, especially if the server in question is an actual server and not a laptop (Microsoft does not support automating Office on servers, let alone doing it from SQL Server). Consider any other solution that lets you keep the import logic in a client: Power Query (optionally with Power Automate), SSIS, PowerShell script if you have to, or pre-process the sheets into a CSV that can be fed directly to `BULK INSERT`. Anything but read it directly from SQL Server.

Comment: Another approach is to automate this in the other direction. Create a task using the windows task manager and open/refresh/close your excel file. Using the OLE automation procedures via tsql is discouraged for good reasons. You have discovered one - they are very difficult to trouble-shoot.

Comment: Well, you should be checking `@status` with `EXEC @status = sp_OA...` on every single invocation. To provide a potentially vague/useful error message for your `raiserror` statement invoke [sp_OAGetErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oageterrorinfo-transact-sql) to find out what the problem is.